# How to use templates to build compile-time generated metadata

Tags: c++, metadata, variadic-templates

In trying to call a variadic template, I was getting errors.
This question has now been split into the error, and the deeper goal which is in [Is it possible to build a const array at compile time using a c++ variadic template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082989/is-it-possible-to-build-a-const-array-at-compile-time-using-a-c-variadic-templ?noredirect=1#comment120333173_68082989)

To test the variadic template in isolation, I tried to just print out the values. So I'm obviously messing up the template somehow:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void test(T first, Args... args) {
  cout << sizeof(first) << '\n';
    test(args...);
}
int main() {
  test(123_u32, 1234_u64, 1.23_f32, 1.23456_f64);
}
```

The error is:

error: no matching function for call to ‘test()’
test(args...);

What I don't understand is, this was taken from Eli Bendersky's blog post, and this works:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T adder(T first, Args... args) {
  return first + adder(args...);
}
```

Comment: You are missing the second variant of `adder` from the blog post that only accepts a single argument: ```template<typename T>
T adder(T v) {
  return v;
}```

Comment: I am unclear what your one question is.  Is it only the test failure?  Please ask one question in a SO question.

Comment: Please split up the question.
The part below the error you are currently encountering should be handled separately.

Comment: ugh! Ok, that was simple. I will split out the deeper question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remember that templates are templates.

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void test(T first, Args... args) {
  cout << sizeof(first) << '\n';
    test(args...);
}
int main() {
  test(123_u32, 1234_u64, 1.23_f32, 1.23456_f64);
}
```

This will expand to

```
void test(uint32_t first, uint64_t arg1, float32_t arg2, float64_t arg3) {
  cout << sizeof(first) << '\n';
  test(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
void test(uint64_t first, float32_t arg1, float64_t arg2) {
  cout << sizeof(first) << '\n';
  test(arg1, arg2);
}
void test(float32_t first, float64_t arg1) {
  cout << sizeof(first) << '\n';
  test(arg1);
}
void test(float64_t first) {
  cout << sizeof(first) << '\n';
  test(); //ERROR
}

int main() {
  test(123_u32, 1234_u64, 1.23_f32, 1.23456_f64);
}
```

To tackle this you can create a specialized version that accepts exactly one arguments, that doesn't call `test()` without arguments.

```
template<typename T>
void test(T first) {
  cout << sizeof(first) << '\n';
}
```

The [mentioned blog post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/), does exactly the same.

---

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @Jarod42 with C++17 and up you don't need to write recursive templates but can directly use the parameter pack using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<typename ...Ts> 
void test(Ts... args) 
{ 
  ((std::cout << sizeof(first) << '\n'), ...);
}
```

Comment: or since C++17, use fold expression: `template<typename ...Ts> void test(Ts... args) { ((std::cout << sizeof(first) << '\n'), ...); }`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. Added this to my answer.