# Is it possible to build a const array at compile time using a c++ variadic template?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, compile-time

The following code attempts to create a typesafe way to generate byte-backed binary data while automatically generating metadata describing the bytes.
Is there any way to generate the metadata at compile time? For example:

```
const Type meta[] = {Type::U32, Type::U64};
```

I'm not even sure that's possible, but if it is please tell me how!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class Type { U8, U16, U32, U64, I8, I16, I32, I64, F32, F64, STRUCT };

void write(char*& buf, uint32_t val) {
    *(uint32_t*)buf = val;
    buf += sizeof(uint32_t);
}

void write(char*& buf, uint64_t val) {
    *(uint64_t*)buf = val;
    buf += sizeof(uint64_t);
}

void writeMeta(char*& buf, uint32_t val) {
    *(uint8_t*)buf = uint32_t(Type::U32);
    buf += sizeof(uint8_t);
}

void writeMeta(char*& buf, uint64_t val) {
    *(uint8_t*)buf = uint32_t(Type::U64);
    buf += sizeof(uint8_t);
}

void writeBuf(char* buf, char*meta) {
}

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void writeBuf(char* buf, char*meta, T first, Args... args) {
  write(buf, first);
    writeMeta(meta, first);
    writeBuf(buf, meta, args...);
}

int main() {
    char buffer[1024];
    char metadata[1024];
    writeBuf(buffer, metadata, uint32_t(2), uint64_t(3));
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        cout << uint32_t(uint8_t(buffer[i])) << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You mean generating a `std::array<uint8_t, N>`?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher that would be fine, or a regular array would be ok. Whatever works. The point is how can the template generate the const array at compile time with the right values

Comment: You should have a look at `constexpr` functions and variables.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, you want something like (C++17):

```
template <typename T>
constexpr Type toType()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<uint8_t, T>) { return Type::U8; }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<uint16_t, T>) { return Type::U16; }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<uint32_t, T>) { return Type::U32; }
    // ...
    else { return Type::STRUCT; }
}

template <typename ...Ts>
constexpr std::array<Type, sizeof...(Ts)> getMeta()
{
    return {{toType<Ts>()...}};
}

static_assert(getMeta<std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>() == {Type::U32, Type::U64});
```